# Java NoSuchMethodError for regex.Matcher.results() when running .jar file

Tags: java, jar, nosuchmethoderror

When I run my app as a .jar file, it returns the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrc
der.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.regex.Matcher.results()Ljav
til/stream/Stream;
        at SalesToExcel.start(SalesToExcel.java:108)
        at SalesToExcel.main(SalesToExcel.java:45)
        ... 5 more
```

However, it works when I run it inside of the Eclipse IDE. Any ideas? I'm not sure if I'm somehow missing a proper jar file even though java.utils.regex should come included in rt.jar. Is there a way to check if this is missing somehow when I package the jar?

[image: Here are the export settings to .jar]

Comment: Probably you are running different Java versions in Eclipse and OS. In OS command prompt what is the result of `java -version` ?

Comment: 1.8.0_221 for java in cmd prompt

In eclipse the config shows: java.runtime.version=11.0.2+9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is your problem. [java.util.regex.Matcher.results](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results()) is in Java since Java 9 and you are running the .jar with Java 8.

Eclipse runs with Java11.

Install as default JRE at least Java9 in your OS (Windows ?).

Comment: Brilliant! That was it. Thank you so much!